# "Both the drivers" versus "both drivers"

Tags: articles, definite-articles

Context: there were two drivers in a single vehicle driving along a test track. Then the vehicle overturned and the drivers were injured.

Which sentence is correct: “The vehicle overturned injuring both the drivers” or “The vehicle overturned injuring both drivers”?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Either "both drivers" or "both of the drivers".

Answer (score 2):

'Both drivers' sounds more adequate to me, because 'both the drivers' would most likely include something else as well — e.g. 'both the drivers and the passengers'.